# How to select every level with different user and user progress

Tags: mysql, database, outer-join

I wanted to make a learning apps with a completed questions progress track on each level. I have 2 tables which contain all the level with its question count, and a table that save an user progress (completed questions) on each level. Here is the record,

Level table:

```
+----------+----------------------+-------------+--------+
| id_level | name                 | jumlah_soal | id_sub |
+----------+----------------------+-------------+--------+
|        1 | Basic Level 1        |           5 |      1 |
|        2 | Basic Level 2        |           6 |      1 |
|        3 | Basic Level 3        |           7 |      1 |
|        8 | Intermediate Level 1 |           5 |      2 |
|        9 | Intermediate Level 2 |           5 |      2 |
|       10 | Intermediate Level 3 |           5 |      2 |
..........................................................
```

Progress Table:

```
+-----------------+---------+-------------+----------+
| id_progreslevel | id_user | completed   | id_level |
+-----------------+---------+-------------+----------+
|               1 |       1 |           2 |        1 |
|               2 |       1 |           3 |        2 |
|               3 |       2 |           2 |        1 |
+-----------------+---------+-------------+----------+
```

---

and when I joined the tables with the following query

```
SELECT IFNULL(progreslevel.id_user, 1) as id_user,
    -> level.*, IFNULL(progreslevel.completed, 0) as completedquestions
    -> FROM level LEFT JOIN progreslevel
    -> ON level.id_level = progreslevel.id_level
    -> WHERE level.id_sub = 1
    -> HAVING id_user = 1;
```

It queries what I wanted:

```
+---------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+--------------------+
| id_user | id_level | name          | jumlah_soal | id_sub | completed questions |
+---------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+--------------------+
|       1 |        1 | Basic Level 1 |           5 |      1 |                  2 |
|       1 |        2 | Basic Level 2 |           6 |      1 |                  3 |
|       1 |        3 | Basic Level 3 |           7 |      1 |                  0 |
+---------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+--------------------+
```

BUT, when I tried to change to query a progress for user ID = 2, it became like this:

```
+---------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+--------------------+
| id_user | id_level | name          | jumlah_soal | id_sub | completed questions |
+---------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+--------------------+
|       2 |        1 | Basic Level 1 |           5 |      1 |                  2 |
|       2 |        3 | Basic Level 3 |           7 |      1 |                  0 |
+---------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+--------------------+
```

---

Yes, the Basic Level 2 is gone because user 2 hadn't done it yet but user 1 had.
This is where I'm stuck, I want to whichever user I choose, its always query all the level, even when the other user had done it. It should be like this:

```
+---------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+--------------------+
| id_user | id_level | name          | jumlah_soal | id_sub | completed questions |
+---------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+--------------------+
|       2 |        1 | Basic Level 1 |           5 |      1 |                  2 |
|       2 |        2 | Basic Level 2 |           6 |      1 |                  0 |
|       2 |        3 | Basic Level 3 |           7 |      1 |                  0 |
+---------+----------+---------------+-------------+--------+--------------------+
```

How do I achieve this?
Thanks in advance and Sorry if you got dizzy either at my explanation or database, I tried my best to translate it, so it's understandable

Comment: But why would id_user 2 appear alongside a level they hadn't completed !?!

Comment: Because what I need is to output all the level and progress, including the progress which haven't been completed by the user, so the user can see which level they haven't complete - @Strawberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure that I understand the requirement, but I think you're after something like this...

```
SELECT l.*
     , 2 id_user
     , COALESCE(MAX(p.completed),0) completed_questions 
  FROM level l 
  LEFT 
  JOIN progress p 
    ON p.id_level = l.id_level 
   AND p.id_user = 2 
 WHERE l.id_sub = 1 
 GROUP 
    BY l.id_level;
```

Comment: Saying thanks is forbidden when commenting, but sir... You have my infinite amount of thanks, i'm so grateful that you helped me...